Change in locale is not affecting the application
I am creating an application with dayjs as the date-time library. In the application I am setting the default locale to "en" at the app level and when I am changing the language in the dropdown, I update the locale. For some reason the locale change is not reflecting inside the app. I am rendering ja locale on the Japanese language selection. What am I doing wrong?
import Component1 from "./Component1";
import Component2 from "./Component2";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { setLocale } from "./time";

const languageOptions = [
  {
    name: "English",
    value: "en",
  },
  {
    name: "Japanese",
    value: "ja",
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");

  useEffect(() => setLocale("en"), []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setLocale(e.target.value);
    setLanguage(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dayjs </h1>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {languageOptions.map(({ name, value }) => (
          <option value={value} selected={language === value}>
            {name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
    </div>
  );
}

import dayjs from "dayjs";
import("dayjs/locale/en");
import("dayjs/locale/ja");

export const formats = {
  LONG_DATE: "LL",
  FULL_DATE_TIME: "LLL",
};

export function setLocale(locale) {
  dayjs.locale(locale);
}

export function getFormat(timestamp, format) {
  return dayjs(timestamp).format(format);
}

export function getCurrentFormat(format) {
  return dayjs().format(format);
}

import { getFormat, formats } from "./time";

export default function Component1() {
  return <h1>Time 1: {getFormat(1721306110, formats.FULL_DATE_TIME)}</h1>;
}



import { getCurrentFormat } from "./time";

export default function Component2() {
  return <h1>Time 2: {getCurrentFormat()} </h1>;
}


I think it's because of dayjs.locale() does not trigger a re-render of your components.
You need to pass the language state as a prop to your components and then use the language prop inside the components to format the dates.
Try this
App component :
import Component1 from "./Component1";
import Component2 from "./Component2";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { setLocale } from "./time";

const languageOptions = [
  {
    name: "English",
    value: "en",
  },
  {
    name: "Japanese",
    value: "ja",
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocale(language);
  }, [language]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setLocale(e.target.value);
    setLanguage(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dayjs </h1>
      <select onChange={handleChange} value={language}>
        {languageOptions.map(({ name, value }) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <Component1 language={language} />
      <Component2 language={language} />
    </div>
  );
}

Component 1 :
import { getFormat, formats } from "./time";

export default function Component1({ language }) {
  return <h1>Time 1: {getFormat(1721306110, formats.FULL_DATE_TIME)}</h1>;
}

Components 2
import { getCurrentFormat } from "./time";

export default function Component2({ language }) {
  return <h1>Time 2: {getCurrentFormat()} </h1>;
}


Unfortunately this did not work.
